# Eclipse new project library zip file error

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

I open eclipse Juno go to file new JDK project (the first new project option), Name the file then go to download the Juno library and I hit agree to those agreement statement. Next I hit download and an error comes up saying that it can't open the zip file. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on ubuntu, try loading eclipse in sudo mode. Also ensure that the zip file has `chmod 777` access.